# pacemaker corosynce lsb resource script( Sybase Database ASE Server and Backup Server)

Tags: bash, rhel, high-availability, pacemaker, lsb

I'm trying to create a lsb resource with pcs on rhel7.2 The "sybase" script is about Sybase Database ASE Server and Backup Server Startup & Stop & Restart $ status script

The script is all pass [Init Script LSB Compliance](http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Pacemaker_Explained/ap-lsb.html), but it doesn't work!

**Error**

```
[root@pldbsv01 ~]# pcs resource create ase157_res lsb:sybase op monitor interval=30s
[root@pldbsv01 ~]# pcs constraint order start gfs2sybasedata_res-clone then ase157_res
    Adding gfs2sybasedata_res-clone ase157_res (kind: Mandatory) (Options: first-action=start then-action=start)

[root@pldbsv01 ~]# pcs constraint colocation add ase157_res with gfs2sybasedata_res-clone
[root@pldbsv01 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: PLDBSV_CLUSTER
Last updated: Wed Apr 20 12:22:51 2016      Last change: Wed Apr 20 12:20:18 2016 by root via cibadmin on pldbsv01-cr
Stack: corosync
Current DC: pldbsv01-cr (version 1.1.13-10.el7-44eb2dd) - partition with quorum
2 nodes and 10 resources configured

Online: [ pldbsv01-cr pldbsv02-cr ]

Full list of resources:

 Resource Group: PLDBSV_RESOURCE
     PLDBSV_VIP (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started pldbsv02-cr
 idrac-pldbsv01 (stonith:fence_ipmilan):    Started pldbsv01-cr
 idrac-pldbsv02 (stonith:fence_ipmilan):    Started pldbsv01-cr
 Clone Set: dlm-clone [dlm]
     Started: [ pldbsv02-cr ]
     Stopped: [ pldbsv01-cr ]
 Clone Set: clvmd-clone [clvmd]
     Started: [ pldbsv02-cr ]
     Stopped: [ pldbsv01-cr ]
 Clone Set: gfs2sybasedata_res-clone [gfs2sybasedata_res]
     Started: [ pldbsv02-cr ]
     Stopped: [ pldbsv01-cr ]
 ase157_res (lsb:sybase):   Stopped

[B]Failed Actions:
* ase157_res_start_0 on pldbsv02-cr 'unknown error' (1): call=41, status=Timed Out, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Wed Apr 20 12:21:35 2016', queued=0ms, exec=20002ms
* ase157_res_start_0 on pldbsv01-cr 'unknown error' (1): call=45, status=Timed Out, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Wed Apr 20 12:19:56 2016', queued=0ms, exec=20002ms[/B]


PCSD Status:
  pldbsv01-cr: Online
  pldbsv02-cr: Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

**My script**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Startup script for Sybase ASE
# Description: Service script for starting/stopping/monitoring \
#              Sybase Adaptive Server on: \
#                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 \
# Release date 2015-08-11
# Version 1 
# Processname: dataserver
# (1) Before running this script, we assume that user has installed
#     Sybase ASE 15.0.2 or higher version on the machine.
# (2) This script should be put under /etc/init.d. Its owner should be "root" with 
#     execution permission.
# (3) You must define the variables "SYBASE" "SERVER" BACKUPSERVER"
# (4) You can change Adaptive Server login name and password in line 96,
#     defaults are "sa" and "sybase"



SYBASE=/opt/sybase
SERVER=PLDBSV
BACKUPSERVER=PLDBSV_BS

# Source environment variables.
. $SYBASE/SYBASE.sh


# Find the name of the script
NAME=`basename $0`


# For SELinux we need to use 'runuser' not 'su'
if [ -x /sbin/runuser ]
then
    SU=runuser
else
    SU=su
fi


# Start sybase Adaptive Server and Backup Server
start() {
    SYBASE_ASE_START=$"Starting ${NAME} Adaptive Server: "
    $SU sybase -c ". $SYBASE/SYBASE.sh; $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/startserver \
-f $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/RUN_${SERVER} > /dev/null"
    ret=$? 
    if [ $ret -eq 0 ]
    then    
        echo -n "$SYBASE_ASE_START                    ["
        echo -n -e "\033[32m Success \033[0m"  
        echo "]"
    else
        echo -n "$SYBASE_ASE_START           ["
        echo -n -e "\033[31m Failed \033[0m"
        echo "]"
                exit 1
    fi

    for ((i=1; i<31; i++))
    do
        sleep 1
        echo "waitting $i sec to prepare Backup Server!"
    done

    SYBASE_BS_START=$"Starting ${NAME} Backup Server: "
    $SU sybase -c ". $SYBASE/SYBASE.sh; $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/startserver \
-f $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/install/RUN_${BACKUPSERVER} > /dev/null"
    ret=$? 
    if [ $ret -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -n "$SYBASE_BS_START                    ["
        echo -n -e "\033[32m Success \033[0m"
        echo "]"
    else
        echo -n "$SYBASE_BS_START                    ["
        echo -n -e "\033[31m Failed \033[0m"
        echo "]"
                exit 1
    fi  
}

#stop sybase adaptive server and backup server
stop() {
    SYBASE_BS_STOP=$"Stopping ${NAME} Backup Server"
    pid=$(pidof backupserver)
    if [ $pid > 0 ]
    then
    $SU root -c "kill -9 $pid > /dev/null"
        echo -n "$SYBASE_BS_STOP                     ["
        echo -n -e "\033[32m Success \033[0m"
        echo "]"
    else
        echo -n "$SYBASE_BS_STOP                     ["
        echo -n -e "\033[31m Failed \033[0m"
        echo "]"
    fi

    SYBASE_ASE_STOP=$"Stopping ${NAME} Adaptive Server: "
    $SU sybase -c ". $SYBASE/SYBASE.sh; isql -S $SERVER -U sa -P sybase < \
$SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/upgrade/shutdown.sql > /dev/null"
    ret=$?
    if [ $ret -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo -n "$SYBASE_ASE_STOP            ["
        echo -n -e "\033[32m Success \033[0m"
        echo "]"
    else
        echo -n "$SYBASE_ASE_STOP            ["
        echo -n -e "\033[31m Failed \033[0m"
        echo "]"
        exit 0
    fi
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

# Check Sybase Adaptive Server and Backup Server status
status() {
    dataserver=$(pidof dataserver)
    backupserver=$(pidof backupserver)
    if [ -n "$dataserver" ]; then
        echo "sybase Adaptive Server is running!"
    else
        echo "sybase Adaptive Server is stopped!" 

    fi

    if [ -n "$backupserver" ]; then     
        echo "sybase Backup Server is running!" && exit 0 || exit $?
    else
        echo "sybase Backup Server is stopped!"
        exit 3
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    status) 
        status
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
esac
```

how to solve the problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Evidently the start operation timed out (see "failed actions"), set the timeout when defining the resource. I'm not sure about pcs syntax for this (I don't use pcs)